# Could not filter out data with WHERE clause after join condition

Tags: mysql

I updated the data in my database but could not filter out data in where clause after joining table.

- [customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KchqF.png)
- [order table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjP8Y.png)

```
CODE{

Use sql_store;
SELECT *
FROM customers c
JOIN orders o 
USING (customer_id)
WHERE state = 'VA'

}
```

O/P:
[The output should list all the users from VA but is giving only one user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAo9U.png)

Comment: Please don't SHOUT — we can read mixed-case text much more easily.

Comment: Apologies Jonathan , will take care of this next time

Comment: Also, don't post pictures of text; include the text directly in the question.

Comment: Try not to use Using clause because your table contain all the different column.

Comment: i have used ON statement instead of using clause ...Still getting the same result as mentioned in output

Comment: Check if the order table has customer_id 1 or not as the customer-id 1 has state 'VA' in Customer table and if order table doesn't have that customer_id then it will not be displayed

Comment: Change `WHERE state = 'VA'` TO `WHERE c.state = 'VA'
`

Comment: No it's not radhe .. i have not created this data base. The data base is created by mosh hamdani ... a professional teacher .. So there is no mistake

Comment: No sibabrat ... :(  i have tried that . but still showing same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output will list all the users who have state 'VA' in Customer table and also that Customer_id present in Order table.

First check manually how many users satisfy this criteria

Comment: Ahhhhh You got it Radhe ankit ... used the outer left join solves this issue .. great insight man ..

Comment: Keep one thing in mind , whenever you got stuck ,try to dry run your code

Comment: Alright thanks Radhe .. I will practise the same :)) Tysm

Answer (score 1):

Try add the table pointer to the column:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers c
JOIN orders o ON c.costumer_id = o.costumer_id
WHERE c.state = 'VA'
```

Comment: Still getting same o/p

Comment: No still the same :(

Comment: The USING clause is equivalent to what you wrote out longhand as the ON clause.